# 'FullTrustProcessLauncher': is not a class or namespace name

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

I am trying to build a UWP with Desktop Extensions. Since this is my first time trying this, I followed this [tutorial](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) to help me get started. All my projects in the solution are written in C++.

However, after setting up everything, when I tried to build the solution, I see the following errors.

```
error C2653: 'FullTrustProcessLauncher': is not a class or namespace name
```

```
error C3861: 'LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync': identifier not found
```

I initially had problems because IntelliSense reported that `FullTrustProcessLauncher` was not found. I was able to mitigate that error by adding a `Windows Desktop Extensions for UWP` reference to the UWP project. After that, IntelliSense no longer complained but I started having errors when compiling.

How do I fix these errors that I get while compiling? Am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know native C++ aren't supported by UWP. Aren't you using C++/CLI?

Comment: I am sure that C++ is supported by UWP. They have a different version. Something called C++/CX or C++/WinRT. I am currently using C++/CX.

Comment: Exactly my point. If you are using C++/CX, please tag the language as [tag:c++-cx], instead of [tag:c++]. if you are using C++/CX. If one knows C++, one may not know about MS-specific variants of the language.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Algirdas. I have changed it now.

Comment: Um, that sample is written in C#, not C++. Where is your C++ code? I suspect you missed something in translation, like, say, a `using namespace` statement.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have ported the C# code to C++ and ensured that all the using namespace statements are present. Since the code is in multiple files, I uploaded it to GitHub. You can find it at (https://github.com/bvishal7/DesktopExtensionSample). Please open the Visual Studio Solution by opening "DesktopExtensionTest.sln" in "DesktopExtensionSample\DesktopExtensionTest\". Thanks.

Comment: You say that you "ensured that all the using namespace statements are present" but you didn't. The FullTrustProcessLauncher is in the Windows::ApplicationModel namespace but you lack a `using` statement for that namespace.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have included it in the "pch.h" header file. This header file has been called in the "MainPage.xaml.cpp" file.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I missed that because [putting `using` statements in header files goes against the CPP Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rs-using-directive). I don't know where you got the 19041 SDK (latest official is 18362). If I use 18362, I get the same error. Something weird, since the Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract is in that SDK, yet C++/CX is not seeing it.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for mentioning the guidelines. I got the 19041 SDK because I was testing the app on an insider build. 

Yes, that is exactly the problem I faced and I just could not understand what was the reason behind the error. Do you know what next steps I can take to get help with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: If I add the call to FullTrustProcessLauncher to an existing C++/CX app that consumes the Desktop Extension SDK, it works (I used [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AnimationMetrics/cpp/), so there must be something funny about the vcxproj itself. Comparing...

Comment: Okay, I got your project to build by changing 19041 to 18362 in the DesktopExtensionTest.vcxproj and in the Package.wapproj. Project then builds as x64 and x86.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you so much. It works for me too! I guess those functions/namespaces might not be supported in 19041 yet.